# How to put an image into a MAT in openCV, through the android NDK (c++)

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm using `OpenCv` through the `Android NDK (using c++)`
I would like to save an image into MAT format and then display it on my android application.

I have saved the image in assets. `imread()` does not work in the NKD because it cannot find the file path to the image, however, I can use AssetManager to load an asset and it finds the path perfectly. This method saves the data into a char* buffer.

How can I, either use something similar to `imread()` to save the image into a MAT, or convert the char* buffer data into a MAT in order to display it on screen and later on manipulate with other `openCV` functions?

Comment: [`cv::imdecode`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e) is the equivalent of `imread` when you already have the data in a buffer.

Comment: @Dan Mašek my code is in the format :

    char* buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*sizeOfImg);
    AAsset_read(img, buffer, sizeOfImg);
so the resulting buffer is in the form char*. imdecode() expects data in the format const_inputArray.

Comment: put the data in a `std::vector<char>` and use `cv::imdecode`

Comment: Don't even have to copy the data to a vector: [`cv::_InputArray(buffer,buffer_size)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#af5fefc8554c4df2697f83033753799e7)

Answer (score 0):

Use code snippet

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL
Java_com_example_opencv_test_NativeLib_checkNativeImage(JNIEnv *env,
                                                    jclass type,
                                                    jobject jBitmap,
                                                    jint width,
                                                    jint height) {

void *pPixelData = nullptr;
if (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, jBitmap, &pPixelData) ==
    ANDROID_BITMAP_RESULT_SUCCESS) {

    // Android bitmap (Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) to Mat
    // Android and OpenCV have different color channels order, just swap it
    // You need cppFlags "-std=c++14" for this code
    // See [opencv_src]\modules\java\generator\src\cpp\utils.cpp for details about PremultiplyAlpha
    // Use https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/android/Utils.html for Mat in Java

    cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat(cvSize(width, height), CV_8UC4, pPixelData); // 4 channels
    cv::Mat img;
    cv::cvtColor(temp, img, CV_BGRA2RGBA);

    // ... use Mat Image


    // back to Android Bitmap
    cvtColor(img, temp, CV_RGBA2BGRA); // Swap colors back
    memcpy(pPixelData, temp.data, static_cast<size_t>(width * height * 4));


    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, jBitmap);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

return EXIT_FAILURE;

}
```