# What to pass to Android's NDK so an image can be loaded with OpenCV?

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk

### info

I have an Android NDK / OpenCV project (running native c++ code).

I'm trying to load an image to the NDK, so I'm loading an image as a bitmap, so I can get it's path.

Instead of passing the whole image to the NDK (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798642/how-to-put-an-image-into-a-mat-in-opencv-through-the-android-ndk-c), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264709/convert-the-base64string-or-byte-array-to-matimage-in-copencv) or others), I want to just pass a string (e.g. the image path) or a pointer or something like this to the NDK, and read the image from the NDK with OpenCV.

I tried to use [OpenCV's Face Detection example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/face-detection) as reference, but it doesn't really do what I'm trying to do.

To get the path string in Java I tried this:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
String imagePath = uri.getEncodedPath();
```

Or this:

```
Cursor imageCursor;
int imageNameIndex, imageSizeIndex;
Uri uri = data.getData();
imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
imageNameIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
String imagePath = imageCursor.getString(nameIndex);
```

Or that:

```
String imageFullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/" + imagePath;
```

Or that:

```
String imageFullPath = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + imagePath;
```

which got me strings like `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/my-image.jpg`, `Pictures/my-image.jpg`, `my-image.jpg` or `/document/image%3A167`.

Then I'm passing the string to the NDK (convert it to `char *`) and try to load an image on C++ with OpenCV's `imread`:

```
Mat image = imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);
```

All of the above trials result in an empty `Mat` object (all `int` values equal `0` and pointers are `NULL`).

I also tried similar approach with pointers.

### question

Is this an OpenCV issue? Should I initialize the `Mat` in a certain way?

If not, what string / pointer should I pass to the NDK so it can load the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pass pointer

#### Java side:

`Activity.java`:

```
// create a mat object with CvType.CV_8UC4, for Android's RGBA_8888
Mat passToNativeMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);

// convert (for example) a bitmap image to Mat object
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, passToNativeMat);

// get the native address of the Mat object created
long passToNativeMatAddress = passToNativeMat.getNativeObjAddr();

// call the Native function
String imageToJNIResult = imageToJNI(passToNativeMatAddress);

// native declarations
public native String imageToJNI(long imagePointer);
```

#### Native side:

`native-lib.cpp`:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_package_activity_imageToJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject thiz,
        jlong imagePointer) {

    Mat& image_in_native = *(Mat*) imagePointer;

    // do something with image Mat object

    string return_string = "Return string";

    return env->NewStringUTF(return_string.c_str());
```

}

## Pass byte array

#### Java side:

```
public native String byteToJNI(byte[] myArray);
```

#### Native side:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_package_activity_byteToJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject thiz,
        jbyteArray array) {

    Mat * mat = ByteToMat(array);

    string return_string = "Return string";

    return env->NewStringUTF(return_string.c_str());

}
```